# Chart.js how to create chart wirhout y-axis for two data sets

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I have two datasets for example (21, 22, 23) and (23, 24, 25) and I would like to present this sets in one line.
I don't need y-axis, I tried to use line chart with option `showLine: false` set to false, but it seems not to be right approach.

I've created mock how it should look;

[image: I've created mock how it should look]

Answer (score 0):

Define your points according to the point input https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point by setting the x value to your value and the y value to -1 or 1 and then disable the yAxes you will get what you want